# Multiple Controllers from a single view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I recently started with CakePHP and so far I'm loving it, specially the scafolding and bake.

I'm building a webapp that will manage applications to companies.  (i.e., where have I applied to, with whom have I spoke, the status of the application(s), how long ago has it been since I did sent/recieved a communication regarding this application.)

I have a model Application and an Action model.  An application has multiple Actions.

When you add a new Application, it does not make sense to add "just" the application but to add one action.  Is there anyway to have my applications add view to connect with two controllers and add the action and application simultaneously?

Please do let me know if my problem is understandable or if you need further clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507552/cakephp-best-way-to-call-an-action-of-another-controller-with-array-as-parameter).