# How to call Controller action in another controller in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I want to use "getpoll" ,which is action of users controller ,in another controller(events controller).

How can i use it?

in advance thanks...to all...

Comment: Does this action have a view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 2.3.8: Calling Another Controller function in CronController.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344988/cakephp-2-3-8-calling-another-controller-function-in-croncontroller-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write the db query of the `getPoll()` action as a method in the poll **model**, that way in your user controller you can just call `$this->User->Poll->getPolls()` to grab the polls, and if associations are setup correctly, `$this->Event->Poll->getPolls()` from your events controller.

For example in your poll model:

```
public function getPoll($userId = null) {
    return $this->find('all', array(..));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use requestAction method of the controller:

```
$this->requestAction('/comments/latest');
```

you can call it differently depending on your needs for details look for the link:

Link to CookBook: [Controller requestAction Method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions)

Comment: You should not use the requestAction for something as simple as this, the proper advice would be to put the getPoll method in the user *model*.

Answer (score 2):

You could share a common piece of code between controllers with components.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/994/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

The cookbook states:

> If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model.
>   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507552/cakephp-best-way-to-call-an-action-of-another-controller-with-array-as-paramete)  post show a different and better approach