# CakePHP 2.3.8: Calling Another Controller function in CronController.php

Tags: controller, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cron-task

For `CakePHP 2.3.8` How can I call Another Controller function in CronController.php

Any ideas?

Comment: guess component is a better alternative? Why do you need to call controller inside another controller?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Below is the code:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Products'); // mention at top

// Instantiation // mention within cron function
$Products = new ProductsController;
// Call a method from
$Products->ControllerFunction();
```

Hope it helps some one !

Comment: This is absolutely not recommended! Depending on what your code does, use [components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) (as @xialinZZZ already mentioned), libraries or [models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html) instead.

Comment: May be, but atleast my work is not stuck at moment, it seems pretty easy way go around for a quick solution finder

Comment: The whole concept of a "cron controller" is *completely* flawed by design. You should use a shell and your data processing logic should be in a model so it can be shared between the controller and shell if needed. I down voted this answer as well because it is one of the most bad things you can do.

Answer (score 7):

I referenced the manual to find a solution to this.

```
public function that_controller_function_you_are_writing () {

    # this is cakes way of running required
    App::import('Controller', 'Users');
    $UsersController = new UsersController;

    # now you can reference your controller like any other PHP class
    $UsersController->that_function_you_needed();
}
```

This is the link:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the `$this->requestAction();` method in your controller action. It's not the most recommended pattern, but it can be useful and can return data or render a view based on your parameters.

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Please explain why this is not recommended?

Answer (score 4):

The `App::import('Controller', 'XXX');`  did not work for me.

I'm using Cake 3.0

After a while I made it work

Function of the controller you want to call:

```
    public function validateSomething($var = null)
    {
         return ...
    }
```

In a different controller, where you need to call the previous function to validate something:

```
 public function index()
    {
      // load the model you need depending on the controller you need to use
        $this->loadModel('User');

     // use this in case you have tu instantiate a new entity
        $user = $this->User->newEntity();
        $user = $this->User->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

     // using the controller on the fly, you could assign it to a var
     // call the function you need
        $result = (new UserController())->validateSomething($user);

     // Test if result has something:
        $this->Flash->success(__($result));
     }
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->link( "Logout,".$user["username"],   array('controller'=>'Users' ,'action'=>'logout') );?>
```

Comment: Can you please add some description of why you think this should work.

Comment: this is not related to the question.