# CakePHP get dispatch data

Tags: cakephp

I'm setting data to `another_view` action using following process. But I can't get the sending  data.

```
$this->autoRender = false; 
$dis = new Dispatcher(); 
$dis->dispatch( 
    array("controller" => "users", "action" => "another_view"), 
    array("data" => $user) 
);
```

How can I get this `$user` data from `another_view`?
please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a function that both methods could call and pass the data as a parameter.

```
class Users extends AppController{

   function another_view(){
       ...
       $this->_myFunction($this->data);
   }

   function _myFunction($data = array()){
       ... //do something with the data
   }
}

class AnotherModel extends AppController{
   function index(){
      App::import('Controller', 'Users');
      $Users = new UsersController;
      $Users->constructClasses();
      $Users->_myFunction($myData);
   }
}
```

However.. it's better [if you put it in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507552/cakephp-best-way-to-call-an-action-of-another-controller-with-array-as-parameter) (if possible)

Hope this helps