# How to call controller in Shell file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using PHP Mailer and i have mail function in app Controller and i want to access it in shell file for crone job.

anyone can guide me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a shell file?

PHP can be run through cron jobs, in there you can include all you need.

Comment: What function is it? Seems like this is a design-failure of yours. This method should not be in the AppController then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Cakephp Shell in order to do something in cron. The question was talked in [How to setup cronjobs in cake php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13949539/1695418) .

**EDIT**: If you need to use something both in your controller and shell, I would suggest to move it to component. In your shell you can do

```
App::import('Component', 'Meteor');
$this->Meteor = new MeteorComponent();
$this->Meteor->flash('New York');
```

In controller

```
$components = array('Meteor');

public function your_action() {
  // code
  $this->Meteor->flash('Paris');
}
```

Comment: Yes i have try that but i want to access app controller's function in shell file

Answer (score 5):

Sorry this is so late but if this were here before it would have helped me, so for future viewers:

Borrowing from a slightly different circumstance at [CakePHP: best way to call an action of another controller with array as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507552/cakephp-best-way-to-call-an-action-of-another-controller-with-array-as-paramete) :

This is working for me so far (Haven't tried more complicated things in a controller yet):
In .../app/Console/Command/BillsShell.php:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Billing');

class BillsShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        $billing = new BillingController();
        $billing->constructClasses(); //I needed this in here for more complicated requiring component loads etc in the Controller
        $billing->test();
    }
}
```

In BillingController.php:

```
class BillingController extends AppController {
    function test() {
        echo "****Big test!!!*****\n\n"; 
    }
}
```

For cake 2.1.3:

```
$> .../app/Console/php cake.php bills

Welcome to CakePHP v2.1.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: .../app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
****Big test!!!*****
```

Answer (score 1):

It is:

```
App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Network');
    App::uses('CakeResponse', 'Network');
    App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    $controller = new AppController(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse());
```

=> $controller is yours

Answer (score 1):

There seems no direct method to call Controller inside Shell [official document](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html), where as we can do a work around, where we can call Model from Shell and in the Model we can call Controller.

Shell:

```
public function main() {
   App::import('Model', 'UserModel');
   $this->UserModel = ClassRegistry::init('UserModel');
   $this->UserModel->callModel();
}
```

Model:

```
function callModel($created) {
        App::import('Controller', 'Pages');
        $something = new PagesController;
        $something->callMe();          
}
```

Controller:

```
public function callMe(){
    echo "Finally, Controller method is called\n";
}
```

FYI: Its just a work around.

Comment: Models should not access controller methods, that's not the point of MVC and it's way too complicated to do something really simpler. What if you call a model method that calls the method in the controller being executed? You will have an infinite loop.