# how to use App controller method in another controller cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

This is cake php 1.3

I have a method in appcontroller called setLog(). I'm trying to use this Method as common for all controllers. but when call this in another controller (Committee Controller ) it says

> Call to undefined method CommitteesController::setLog()

I need to know how to call this function correctly.

## AppController

```
App::import('Controller', 'ActionLogs');
  class AppController extends Controller {

 public function setLog($action,$remark,$status){

    $logs = new ActionLogsController;
    $logs->constructClasses();
    $data = ['action'=>$action,'user'=>$this->Auth->user('id'),'remark'=>$remark,'status'=>$status];
    $logs->add($data);
}
```

}

## Committees Controller

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Committee->create();
        if ($this->Committee->save($this->data)) {
            //create a log for success
            $this->setLog('add new committee',json_encode($this->data),1);

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The committee has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The committee could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            //create a log for failed
            $this->setLog('add new committee',json_encode($this->data),0);
        }
    }
    $committeeTypes = $this->Committee->CommitteeType->find('list');

    $cond = array('group_id' => 2,'is_active' => '1');
    $cond2 = array('group_id' => 4,'is_active' => '1');

    $secretaryUserids = $this->Committee->SecretaryUserid->find('list', array('conditions' => $cond));
    $assistantSecretaryUserids = $this->Committee->AssistantSecretaryUserid->find('list', array('conditions' => $cond2));
    $this->set(compact('committeeTypes', 'secretaryUserids', 'assistantSecretaryUserids'));
}
```

Comment: You should find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511441/6537599)

Comment: I have done, calling method in another controller. cakephp book says "Controller attributes and methods created in your AppController will be available to all of your application’s controllers. It is the ideal place to create code that is common to all of your controllers." .. but i need to know about app controller

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of the following two:

Iheritance: Create a BaseController where you can put all the methods shared by the controlers:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
      public function setLog() 
      {
           // Code here
      }
}

class YourController extends BaseController 
{
     public function yourControllerFunction()
     {
         $this->setLog();
     } 
}
```

`setLog()` has to be public or protected, not private, or it would work only inside BaseController.

It may be that your `AppController` is what I'm calling `BaseController` above, so what you have to do is simply

```
class YourController extends AppController
```

and you'll be able to use the `setLog()` function.

Another way of sharing functions is using Traits:

```
trait LoggerTrait
{
    public function setLog()
    {
        // Code here
    }
}

class YourController extends Controller
{
    use LoggerTrait;

    public function yourControllerFunction()
    {
        $this->setLog();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes I did what you explained in first block.. just a public function to echo something in Base controller (Appcontroller), then I called it in child controller. thing is it says Call to undefined method CommitteesController::test().

Comment: Is your CommiteeController extending AppController in the class declaration? Only require/import is not enough

Comment: YES, class CommitteesController extends AppController {